# Sharing a dial-up connection from Ubuntu 12.04 to another on a LAN

Tags: 12.04, modem, lan, connection-sharing

I need to share the dial-up connection from my Ubuntu machine to another locally connected machine. LAN IP of my client is `192.168.0.2`.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/412456/edit) your question and add more details such as how your PC is configure to connect internet, how the other PC is relating to your PC or connected... etc. This is will help us to identify the network set-up & assist you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called "IP Masquerade" (or IP Masquerading). You have some tutorials there:
http://oreilly.com/openbook/linag2/book/ch11.html

and a more detailled one there: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/IP-Masquerade-HOWTO/index.html